# drupal img tags not being displayed with clean urls

Tags: html, drupal, tags

So im using drupal to set up a simple web project. I was using img tags to display a few images.
simple img tags like

```
<img src="images/home.jpg" />
```

everything was working fine until i switched on clean urls and suddenly all the images disappeared. They still appear in the page source code just dont display.
How do i fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `theme_image` instead. For example:

```
print theme_image("images/home.jpg","My Alternate Text","My Title Text");
```

Alternatively, if you are putting these images inside the body of a node, and you don't want to use PHP, then you need to get Drupal's 'base path' on the front of your image source.

For example, change your image source to `'/images/home.jpg'` and that should work (if the images directory is inside your base www directory).

Answer (score 0):

Install [Pathologic](http://drupal.org/project/pathologic) and activate it on each of your input formats (Drupal 6) or text formats (Drupal 7).